# trigger a dag from airflow2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using this link: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf in order to trigger a DAG using airflow2.

However I am getting this error:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: `https://myairflow/api/v1/dags/lmbr-agentgroup-gcs-to-raw/dagRuns`

However there aren't any place to put some kind of authentication in the code provide in the link of google material.

Does anyone faced this problem and know how to fixed?

I was using the default user in cloud function which is: appengine. after that I found more information and use this command to list all user who has permission
gcloud composer environments run myAirflowEnv --location=southamerica-east1 users -- list
and I used one of this user on cloud function, but it didn't work as well.

same error: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://myAirflow/api/v1/dags/mydag/dagRuns

Comment: Have you checked the assigned role/permissions to your `service account` you are using?

Comment: The service account has role/permission but what I think is strange is I don't pass  any information about service account on googles' doc.

I dont know how to set this.

Comment: I have research and a found more information. I was using  default account which is app engine, after that I have list all users on airflow2 list and had use this user in the cloud function. it didnt work either.

Comment: What are the roles you assigned to your service account?

Comment: do know what roles I need to assing? Because I have tried some roles but didn't work as well.

Comment: Try assigning `Composer User` role and then test your use case again.

Comment: I'm getting this as well. Have tried with multiple different Service Accounts (all with at least Composer User), and used both a key.json file and the default reference to create the credentials. Unfortunately all the requests have a 401 response